# Spring + Powermock + JUnit call another service from one service - NullPointerException

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock

Getting NullPointerException. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Getting NullPointer when it calls

```
Teacher t = teacherService.getTeacherDetails();
```

I did debug and see teacherService is null. I am not why it is null as I am already mocking this object in my test class.

**StudentServiceTest.java**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({StudentService.class, TeacherService.class})
public class StudentServiceTest{

    @InjectMocks
    StudentService studentService;

    @InjectMocks
    TeacherService teacherService;

    @Mock
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Mock
    private TeacherRepository teacherRepository;

    @Test
    public void getStudentInformation() {
        Student student = new Student();
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();

        when(studentRepository.getStudentDetails()).thenReturn(student);
        when(teacherRepository.getTeacherDetails()).thenReturn(teacher);

        Student student = studentService.getStudentInformaition();

    }
```

**StudentService.java**

```
   private TeacherService teacherService;

   @Autowired
    public StudentService(TeacherService teacherService) {
        this.teacherService = teacherService;
    }

    public Student getStudentInformaition() {
        Teacher t = teacherService.getTeacherDetails();
        // some logic
        Student s = studentRepository.getStudentDetails();
       // some more logic
       return s;
    }
```

**TeacherService.java**

```
 public Teacher getTeacherDetails() {
        Teacher t = teacherRepository.getTeacherDetails();
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: since you are unit testing `StudentService` then you should only inject mocks into your instance of `StudentService` including a mock instance of `TeacherService`

Comment: What does `getStudentInformaition()` return? `Student s`?

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning yes, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this code

```
@InjectMocks
StudentService studentService;
```

injects defined mock object instances into the `studentService` instance, but the instance of `TeacherService` is not a mock and therefor not injected as a mock into the `studentService` instance.

You should adjust your code to something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({StudentService.class, TeacherService.class})
public class StudentServiceTest{

    @InjectMocks
    StudentService studentService;

    @Mock
    TeacherService teacherService;

    @Mock
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Test
    public void getStudentInformation() {
        Student student = new Student();
        Teacher teacher = mock(Teacher.class);

        when(studentRepository.getStudentDetails()).thenReturn(student);
        when(teacherService.getTeacherDetails()).thenReturn(teacher);
        when(teacher.getFoo()).thenReturn(???);

        Student student = studentService.getStudentInformaition();

    }
```

Note that `teacherService` is now a mock object instance and `TeacherRepository` is no longer needed at all

Comment: my goal is to call student service that will call teacher service and execute the business logic. If I just mock teacher service, my goal will not be fulfilled.

Comment: then you are not **unit** testing `StudentService`. If you really, really want to go down this path then you'll need to avoid the magic of `@InjectMocks` and manually construct an instance of `StudentService`

Comment: @SK. Shouldn't you test `teacherService` in the `TeacherService` class?

Comment: @SK. BTW `@Autowired` is a Spring thing and is not playing a role here. PowerMockito will ignore that annotation